Scrape the latitude and longitude from the website
I want to convert a list of zip codes into a DataFrame of latitude and longitude using data from this website: Free Map Tools.
https://www.freemaptools.com/convert-us-zip-code-to-lat-lng.htm#google_vignette
Here’s my code, but it’s not returning the latitude and longitude data. How can I improve it ?
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_lat_lng(zip_code):
    # URL of the form processing page
    url = 'https://www.freemaptools.com/convert-us-zip-code-to-lat-lng.htm'
    
    # Create a session to handle cookies and headers
    session = requests.Session()
    
    # Send a GET request to get the initial form and any hidden data
    response = session.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()
    
    # Parse the page with BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    # Find form data (if needed)
    # Note: The actual form data extraction depends on how the website is structured
    # For simplicity, assume there's no hidden form data to worry about
    
    # Prepare the data to send in the POST request
    data = {
        'zip': zip_code
        # Include any other required form fields here if necessary
    }
    
    # Send a POST request with the zip code data
    response = session.post(url, data=data)
    response.raise_for_status()
    
    # Parse the resulting page
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
    # Extract latitude and longitude (you need to adjust these selectors based on the website's      structure)
    lat = soup.find('span', {'id': 'latitude'}).text.strip()
    lng = soup.find('span', {'id': 'longitude'}).text.strip()
    
    return lat, lng


# Example 
zip_code = ['97048','63640','63628']
latitude, longitude = get_lat_lng(zip_code)
print(f'Latitude: {latitude}, Longitude: {longitude}')


query latitude and longitude data from https://www.freemaptools.com/convert-us-zip-code-to-lat-lng.htm#google_vignette

Querying a list of zip code,i.e. ['97048','63640','63628'], and obtain the latitude and longitude for each zip.

It results in error message.



Why? Did you look if they provide the original data, or if they link to the original data. Try not to scrap if you can get data (and from website name, I assume they just aggregate data they found easily on Internet)

It seems that I cannot find their original data source.

A quick googling, and I found from our sister site: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5114/obtaining-up-to-date-list-of-us-zip-codes-with-latitude-and-longitude-geocodes  and  also https://gist.github.com/erichurst/7882666 (which gives you hints where to find sources).  Next time try harder to look data.

The lat and long values from the site you provided are ok,but their values are quite different from what I am looking for.  Anyway, thanks.

Try:
import requests

api_url = (
    "https://api.promaptools.com/service/us/zip-lat-lng/get/?zip={}&key=17o8dysaCDrgvlc"
)

zips = ["97048", "63640", "63628"]

headers = {
    "Origin": "https://www.freemaptools.com",
}

for z in zips:
    url = api_url.format(z)
    data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    print(z, data)

Prints:
97048 {'status': 1, 'output': [{'zip': '97048', 'latitude': '46.053228', 'longitude': '-122.971330'}]}
63640 {'status': 1, 'output': [{'zip': '63640', 'latitude': '37.747435', 'longitude': '-90.363484'}]}
63628 {'status': 1, 'output': [{'zip': '63628', 'latitude': '37.942778', 'longitude': '-90.484430'}]}


Your code works for me.
